# Google Cloud Shell does not auto-detect PHP, shows as Plain Text

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Today I noticed that somehow my PHP files are not being auto-detected in Google Cloud Shell.  When I open any PHP file, the code editor auto-detects as `Plain Text`.

When I scroll among the available languages in `Select Language Mode`, I cannot see that PHP is available.  It's just not there.

How do I restore PHP in my Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 0):

There's an existing [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/171269256) and it appears that there's already an internal feature request to bring this feature on Cloud Shell Editor (based on Theia).

I suggest that you check out the link and indicate that you're having the similar issue so for it to gain ["stars"](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: I added a comment to the issue tracker to let the team know that language support for PHP is currently missing from Cloud Shell.